# C++ #include only loading one namespace?

Tags: c++, xcode, namespaces

probably a stupid question but I can't get this to work for some reason. I'm quite new to C++ so I think I might have some misunderstanding somewhere.

graphics.hpp:

```
#ifndef Airport_game_hpp
#define Airport_game_hpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

namespace graphics {

    namespace gl{

        static SDL_Window *mainWindow;
        static SDL_GLContext mainContext; 

        bool initGL();

        bool destroyGL();

    }
}

#endif
```

game.hpp:

```
#ifndef Airport_game_hpp
#define Airport_game_hpp




namespace game{


    void render();

}



#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graphics/graphics.hpp"
#include "game/game.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    std::cout << "Starting application \n";

    if (!graphics::gl::initGL()){
        std::cout << "OpenGL initialization failed \n";
        return false;
    }

    //Test
    game::render(); //This line says: Use of undeclared identifier "game"

    graphics::gl::destroyGL();
    std::cout << "Exit successful \n";
}
```

If I swap the order of the #include-s on main.cpp the "game" namespace is seen but not the "graphics" one. It seems like it only sees one at a time. What am I misunderstanding here?

Thanks!

Comment: My mistake sorry, updated the question :)

Comment: Your "graphics" header has an include guard that looks like it belongs in the  "game" header. Does the real header also use `Airport_game_hpp` as a guard, even though the posted code doesn't?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just realised. That's what a fried brain does to you! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the same include guard in both headers. Ideally the include guard should reflect the name of the module or header, but you should at least change one of them, in order to make them both unique.

Answer (score 2):

Both headers use the same include guard: `Airport_game_hpp`. This means that the second header to be included will be ignored, since its guard has already been defined by the first.

Change the guard for `graphics.hpp` to `Airport_graphics_hpp` and, in general, make sure your guard names are unique.